# make alternate letters of a word to uppercase after reversing the word

Tags: c

input: bangalore

output: eRoLaGnAb

the below is the code which i tried to write on my own but i was not able to get the desired results

```
main()
{
int i,j;
char s[10];
printf("input:");
for(j=0;j<2;j++){
scanf("%[^\n]s",&s[j]);}
char r = strrev(s[j]);
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
    {
            printf("\n%s",r[i]);
    }
    else if(i%2!=0)
    {
            printf("%s",r[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the point of that for cycle? Also, you are trying to save a string in a char (s[i] is a char not a char*). Just `scanf("%[^\n]s",s)`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r` is a `char` not a string, you can not use use a subset `r[i]`

Change to

```
char *r = strrev(s);
```

Notice `strrev(s);` instead of `strrev(s[j]);`, or just call `strrev(s);` without an intermediate pointer, `strrev` reverses the string in place.

And in this part:

```
if (i%2==0)
{
    printf("\n%s",r[i]);
}
else if (i%2!=0)
{
    printf("%s",r[i]);
}
```

if `i` is divisible by 2 there is no need to test again if `i` is not divisible by 2, should be:

```
if (i%2==0)
{
    printf("\n%s",r[i]);
}
else
{
    printf("%s",r[i]);
}
```